# Promise is resolving every "if"condition instead of returning one only

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I'm trying to return a specific response, depending on some data I get. The problem is that everytime it ends up returning the last response, even though it has been thru the correct conditions :

```
api.get('/database-manager/request-status', async (lambdaRequest, lambdaResponse, next) => {
        if (connectionPool == null) {
            connectionPool = await mySQLConnectionPool();
        }
        requestId = lambdaRequest.headers["request-id"]
        const res = await new Promise(
            async function (resolve, reject) {
                await getRequests()
                for (let index in requestIds) {
                    console.log(`requestId in header : ${requestId}`)
                    if (requestId == requestIds[index].request_id) {
                        console.log(`id in list : ${requestIds[index].request_id}`)
                        requestStatus = requestIds[index].request_status
                        console.log("am in the first if ")
                        if (requestStatus == 'Finished') {
                            console.log("am in the finished if ")
                            ec2InstanceLink = requestIds[index].instance_link
                            let response = {
                                "statusCode": 200,
                                "headers": {},
                                "isBase64Encoded": false,
                                "body": ec2InstanceLink
                            }
                            resolve(response)
                        } else {
                            console.log("am in the not finished if ")
                            let response = {
                                "statusCode": 200,
                                "headers": {},
                                "isBase64Encoded": false,
                                "body": JSON.stringify({status: requestStatus})
                            }
                            resolve(response)
                        }
                    }
                    console.log("cannot find")
                    let response = {
                        "statusCode": 200,
                        "headers": {},
                        "isBase64Encoded": false,
                        "body": "Request-Id doesn't exist"
                    }
                    resolve(response)
                }
            }
        )
        return res;
    }
)
```

And this is the console log, proving that even though it's been in the correct situation, it hasn't returned the right response. :

```
1600950719600   START RequestId: 3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7 Version: $LATEST
1600950721777   2020-09-24T12:32:01.777Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    requestId in header : 911e8b872dbe7fc8a2821008bf8af87c
1600950721795   2020-09-24T12:32:01.777Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    cannot find
1600950721815   2020-09-24T12:32:01.815Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    requestId in header : 911e8b872dbe7fc8a2821008bf8af87c
1600950721815   2020-09-24T12:32:01.815Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    id in list : 911e8b872dbe7fc8a2821008bf8af87c
1600950721815   2020-09-24T12:32:01.815Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    am in the first if
1600950721815   2020-09-24T12:32:01.815Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    am in the not finished if
1600950721815   2020-09-24T12:32:01.815Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    cannot find
1600950721815   2020-09-24T12:32:01.815Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    requestId in header : 911e8b872dbe7fc8a2821008bf8af87c
1600950721815   2020-09-24T12:32:01.815Z    3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7    INFO    cannot find
1600950721836   END RequestId: 3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7
1600950721836   REPORT RequestId: 3436e868-b36f-4d51-88c0-0c6b3d06bbb7  Duration: 2235.83 ms    Billed Duration: 2300 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 94 MB  Init Duration: 529.96 ms
```

Comment: Why the `new Promise` construct? Where is `requestIds` defined?

Comment: well I’m just storing the promise in a variable for now, I might use it later.

Comment: What happens if you add a `return;` after the `resolve` statements?

Comment: @Christian Still isn’t working unfortunately.

Comment: Why is "cannot find" etc *inside* the for loop? You don't know that the element hasn't been found until the for loop has completed!

Comment: See if you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). In combination, they will allow you to simplify the code significantly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you call `resolve` multiple times but only the first one is effective.

The structure simplified:

```
await new Promise(
            async function (resolve, reject) {
                for (...) {
                    if (...) {
                        if (...) {
                            resolve(response)
                        } else {
                            resolve(response)
                        }
                    }
                    resolve(response)
                }
            }
        )
```

The `resolve` is called in every iteration of the for loop, and promises can be resolved only once. Since the code is synchronous it will process all the request ids, but the result of the `await new Promise` will be the *first* response, which it the `Request-Id doesn't exist`.

That's why you see a wrong response. To fix this, you need to resolve the promise only once. How to do this depends on what you want to achieve, if you search for a matching responseId it can be as easy as moving the last `resolve` out of the for loop.